# Code Snippets, with all placeholders selected

Tags: xcode

In Xcode, you can create a Snippet with multiple placeholders using a similar token, and using ⌥⌘E, you can select all of them, something like this:

```swift
func foo() {
    var <#name#>: String?
    var some<#name#>: String?
    var another<#name#>OfSomething: String?
}
```

But when importing `SwiftUI` and using the `view` snippet, Xcode can already have all of the tokens selected. Moreover, the selected tokens are in different scopes (this will not work with ⌥⌘E shortcut we create). The snippets cannot be seen in the 'Snippets' window and does not seems to be using tokens at all?
Can we do something similar? Or this is an internal Xcode implementation?